# Why is my constant not pointing to new value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, constants

If i am not wrong, the pointer that the `variable` name is using cannot change in memory, but the thing the variable `points` to might change.

```
let name = "google";
const foo = name;
console.log(foo); //prints google
name = "yahoo"; 
console.log(foo); //prints google again instead of yahoo
```

Should it not print yahoo, as the variable name's value has been changed..  Can anyone explain me this.

Another example, where its changes...

```
const foo = [];
foo.push("test");
console.log(foo); // outputs ["test"]
```

I am getting confused here, can anyone explain me this.

Comment: The first example isn’t specific to constants. The primitive string is copied, there’s no reference being passed. In the second case the reference doesn’t change, the properties of the object are not constant, only the binding of the object to the reference `foo` is constant. To achieve an object with constant properties, use `const foo = Object.freeze([]);`. In a nutshell, `const foo = `…`;` just prevents you to use a future `foo = `…`;`.

Comment: `const` means mutation allowed `const xs = [1,2]; xs.push(3)`, reassignment prohibited `const ys = [1,2]; ys = [1,2,3] // fails`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example uses an immutable string and the second uses a mutable object.

JS strings are immutable after being declared or created, so `foo` is not a reference to `name`'s value, it points to the string. You're not changing the strings, you're pointing to a different one.

The array variable points to the object and continues pointing to the same object after it's been mutated. You're still pointing to the same object, however, since `const` is not deep.

This also highlights a common misunderstanding with JS' `const`, which functions more like Java's `final` than C++'s `const`. You are declaring a *variable* as `const`, not an instance of the object, so it only prevents you from reassigning to the variable, it does not prevent you from mutating the underlying object.

Answer (score 2):

From MDN:

> The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned.

This means that you can change the value assigned to a `const`, say by changing array or object, but cannot assign a new value to the `const` variable. E.g.:

**Valid**:

```js
const a = [];
a.push(5);
console.log(a);

const b = {};
b['foo'] = 'bar';
console.log(b);
```

**Invalid**: This will throw error

```js
const a = [];
a = [5];
console.log(a);

const b = {};
b = {'foo': 'bar'};
console.log(b);
```